# Add/Remove menuItem not working in onPrepareOptionsMenu function

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, navigation-drawer, menuitem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmHrU.png)I am a beginner and i am trying to add and remove menuItem dynamically.
Here is my MainActivity.kt
I have two popups where in one popup i am asking for first name, last name, email, phone number.
and in second popup i am asking for an otp which is hardcoded to "1". After entering "1" as OTP signUp and logIn menuItem should be removed and Orders,Cart,Profile,Logout menuItems should appears.
But someHow it is not happening
Please help me!

```
package com.example.gobikes

import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.app.TimePickerDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.example.gobikes.models.searchInputs
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.drawableLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.signup_popup.*
import java.io.Serializable
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = null
    private var actionBarDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle? = null
    private var popupView: View? = null
    private var popupWindow: PopupWindow? = null
    private var myMenu: Menu? = null
    public var LOGIN_FLAG: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        drawerLayout = drawableLayout
        actionBarDrawerToggle =  ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,customToolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close)
        drawerLayout!!.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle!!)
        actionBarDrawerToggle!!.syncState()
        setSupportActionBar(customToolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.title = ""
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        

        
    }

    fun onClickSignUpButton(view: View){
        if(signupNullCheck()){
            val signUp = popupView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.signUpCardView) as CardView
            val signUpOTP = popupView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.signUpOTPCardView) as CardView
            signUp.visibility = View.GONE
            signUpOTP.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide valid inputs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    fun onClickVerifyButton(view: View){
        val otp = popupView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.OTPBox) as EditText
        if(otp.text!!.isNotEmpty()){
            if(otp.text!!.toString() == "1"){
                LOGIN_FLAG = true
                popupWindow!!.dismiss()
                invalidateOptionsMenu()
            }
            else{
                Log.e("OTP", otp.text.toString())
                Log.e("OTP", otp.text.toString().trim())
                Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect OTP. Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter OTP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }


   

    private fun signupNullCheck(): Boolean{

        val firstName = popupView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.firstNameBox) as EditText
        val lastName = popupView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.lastNameBox) as EditText
        val email = popupView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.emailBox) as EditText
        val phoneNumber = popupView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.phoneNumberBox) as EditText

        return firstName.text!!.isNotEmpty() && lastName.text!!.isNotEmpty() && email.text!!.isNotEmpty() && phoneNumber.text!!.isNotEmpty()
    }


    private fun showSignupPopup(view: View){
        // inflate the layout of the popup window
        val inflater:LayoutInflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signup_popup, null)

        // create the popup window
        val width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        val height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        val focusable = true

        // show the popup window
        // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window token
        popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, width,height, focusable)
        popupWindow!!.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0,0)




    }

    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menu!!.removeItem(R.id.loginMenu)
        menu.removeItem(R.id.signUpMenu)
        var cartMenu = menu!!.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.cartMenu,2, "Cart")
        cartMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_cart_menu_icon)
        var profileMenu = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.profileMenu,3, "Profile")
        profileMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_profile_menu_icon)
        var ordersMenu = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.ordersMenu,4, "Order")
        ordersMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_order_menu_icon)
        var logoutMenu = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.logoutMenu,5, "Logout")
        logoutMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logout_menu_icon)
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    }



    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.signUpMenu -> showSignupPopup(navigationView)
        }
        drawableLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always seem to be doing the same thing irrespective of if the user is signed-in or not. Change your `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to clear the menu first and then show only the relevant menu items. Something like this:

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menu?.clear()
    if (LOGIN_FLAG){
        // add cart, profit, order etc menu items here
    }else{
        // add login and signup menu items here
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

Comment: I am calling  invalidateOptionsMenu() when login is complete which automatically calls onPrepareOptionsMenu(). But My problem here is that menu is not changing. I even tried your suggetion to clear the menu and then add items in it. But that is also not working. I tried to log menu parameter of onPrepareOptionsMenu function and it points to null. Is that a problem.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the call to `onCreateOptionsMenu` where you have to inflate the menu before you make changes to it in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. This guide may help: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/menus#ChangingTheMenu

Comment: Did what you commented. But now it is displaying same menu twice. Somehow it is neglecting onPrepareOptionsMenu function call.  override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.navigation_items)

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

Comment: Attached an image

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the problem after your last comment, you are dealing the new menu everytime, that is why it's not working. You define global myMenu and not using it. Just get initial menu and use that:

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_menu, menu)
        myMenu = menu
        // now you have the menu created initially, 
        // and you need to use this myMenu from now on.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
```

Comment: Not working. Its just duplicating the initial menu items. I dont know somehow adding and removal of menu itmes atre not happening

Comment: apparently in function  onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) menu is null for me